# Selenium scraper for Instagram can't handle multiple users

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, web

This is the code of web scraping Instagram using Selenium with Python:

```py
def direct_message(self, usernames, message):
        try:
            # Open Direct Message section
            dm_btn = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@aria-label='Direct messaging - 0 new notifications link']//div//div[@class='x9f619 xxk0z11 xii2z7h x11xpdln x19c4wfv xvy4d1p']//*[name()='svg']"))
            )
            dm_btn.click()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Direct Message button not found: {e}")
            return  # Stop execution if the DM button is not found

        sleep(5)

        click_search_dm = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(text(),'Send message')]")
        click_search_dm.click()
        sleep(5)

        try:
            # Find the search input field
            search_dm = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/input'))
            )

            # Send messages to profiles
            for username in usernames:
                search_dm.clear()  # Clear the search input field
                search_dm.send_keys(username)
                sleep(2)

                try:
                    # Wait for the search results to load and click on the profile
                    profile_click = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
                        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@role='presentation'][1]//a"))
                    )
                    profile_click.click()
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Error occurred while clicking on the profile: {e}")
                    continue  # Continue to the next iteration if clicking on the profile fails

                send_msg = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(text(),'Send message')]")
                send_msg.click()
                sleep(5)

                type_msg = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//textarea")
                type_msg.send_keys(message)
                sleep(5)

                sending_text = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(),'Send')]")
                sending_text.click()
                sleep(5)

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error occurred while searching DM: {e}")
```

The code describes the DM section which is direct message for web scraping in Instagram. What I have done up to now is I have integrated Google sheet API and credentials from the sheet the username can be fetched and the search DM works but it works fine one only one user but if I tried to multiple user after finishing one DM the other gets interrupted.

Comment: Could you add more context on the error you're facing? Also what are you trying to do exactly? Do you mean another user as in authenticating with other credentials? Or searching for other users on the search bar? It'd help if you could add the code on how/what you attempted to do.